# How to find z and standard deviation, when both are unknown?

Tags: statistics

I linked the question, I tried everything, but I just can't find a way to find z.

[image]

Comment: Is it asked too much to have you actually type the question text?

Comment: May we see "everything" that you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will just try to get you started with the first part.
You have $X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu=1.9,\,\sigma)$ and you
know 
$$ 0.8 = P(X > 1.85) = P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} > \frac{1.85-1.9}{\sigma} \right) = P\left(Z > \frac{1.85-1.9}{\sigma} = c \right),$$
where $Z$ is standard normal.

From software or printed normal tables you can find $c$ and then solve
for $\sigma.$ Obviously, $c$ must be negative because 80% of the probability
lies above it.

I urge my students to draw sketches to help with problems like this.
Maybe the figure below will help you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that equation still has 2 unknows, c and stand deviation

Comment: But using normal tables you can _find_ $c$. Then solve for $\sigma.$